# ¿Qué connotación tiene la construcción impersonal al pedir permiso o cosas?

Tags: gramática, oraciones-impersonales

[Esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-do-you-use-se-puede) me dio varios temas para pensar. En mi respuesta dije primero que preguntar si algo "se puede", en impersonal, cuando en realidad uno quiere que le den algo, es descortés.

> "¿Se podrá tomar una cerveza fría acá?"

Luego y a partir de un comentario de @aparente001 lo cambié porque entiendo que ese distanciamiento que da el impersonal puede ser, por el contrario, una forma de respeto o de suavizar un pedido.

> "¿Se puede llamar larga distancia desde este teléfono?"

Entonces: ¿es descortés el pedido impersonal, o es respetuoso? ¿De qué depende? ¿Es sólo el tono o la actitud? ¿Se trata sólo de diferencias culturales o regionales? ¿Qué recomendación se le haría a un estudiante de castellano sobre su uso?

Answer (score 1):

Pues es que no puedes pedir cosas de forma impersonal, cuando lo haces de manera impersonal lo que estas solicitado es información, no autorización.

Si haces la segunda pregunta

> "¿Se puede llamar larga distancia desde este teléfono?"

Y saltas directo a usar el teléfono después de que te dije que "si", pues lo considero un descaro.

Donde pareciera que el su uso es impersonal es cuando le solicitas a alguien que haga algo por ti

> “Puede salir?”, “Puede acompañarme?”

Pero creo que en lugar de ser impersonal, se está usando implícitamente el pronombre “usted”

---

**Edit:**
Ya vi la pregunta anterior y en efecto, no se está utilizando el “se puede” para pedir permiso para entrar, de hecho, se está preguntando si la entrada está disponible.

Esto se puede corroborar por que por lo común esta frase es únicamente utilizada en lugares públicos, por ejemplo :

Al llegar a una tienda puedes preguntar “se puede?” pero no suena lógico decir “puedo pasar?”

Caso contrario: al cuarto de tu hermano es más lógico preguntar “puedo pasar” a preguntar “se puede”, aunque ambas son válidas en su propio contexto.

**Conclusión:**

> Usas **“se puede”** para cosas que no necesitan permiso
>
> Usas **“puedo”** para cosas que necesitan permiso

**Postmortem**

Creo aquí que el problema está en el uso y la costumbre más que en el significado de lo que se está diciendo.

“Se Puede” es para preguntar lo que es posible, no para pedir, Puedes preguntar “se puede salir a la calle después de las 8 de la noche?” y tal vez creas que estas pidiendo permiso, pero lo que estás haciendo es que estas pidiendo información, y con base a esa información deduces que tienes o que pediste permiso, habría que buscar los usos y costumbres de cada región e incluso familia, pero considero que utilizarlo para pedir es un uso y costumbre muy dentro del ambiente familiar que no debería exteriorizarse a otros ámbitos más formales, sobre todo si queremos llegar a tener una comunicación asertiva eficiente..

Comment: Explicación, Ejemplo, Conclusión, sin errores ortográficos, me merezco una medalla xD

Comment: Si le preguntas a alguien "¿Puede salir?" es, como dijiste, una pregunta formal en "usted", no impersonal. Por otra parte, yo apuntaba a esto: que si bien por lógica una pregunta impersonal no puede ser un pedido a alguien particular, en la práctica a veces sí lo es. Y a mí me parecía que "pedir impersonalmente" era siempre descortés, pero @aparente001 señaló que a veces es de hecho más cortés que hacerlo directamente. Yo sí pregunto a veces "¿Se puede?" antes de pasar a una habitación, y estoy pidiendo permiso para entrar, ni más ni menos.

Comment: Mike, bravo, me alegra ver esto. Es un gran avance. // Creo que lo que Pablo está preguntando es esto: "Se puede...?" es una "construcción *impersonal*", y este término es una descripción *gramatical*.  Ahora, ¿cómo reacciona la gente en tu región ante esta construcción? (Tu respuesta me dio la impresión que estabas tal vez confundiendo forma y función.) // Leyendo tu respuesta, no me quedó del todo claro en cuáles casos crees que esta construcción es cortés o descortés, en cuáles se suaviza el mensaje, etc.