# ¿Cómo se pide comida amablemente/cortésmente?

Tags: expresiones, diferencias-regionales, subjuntivo, comida, cortesía

Por lo general, para incorporar un tono amable en el diálogo, se usa el imperfecto de subjuntivo:

> Mi hija **quisiera** una torta.

**¿Qué otras maneras de pedir comida cortésmente existen?** Específicamente, busco:

- un modo de incluir «por favor» gramaticalmente en la oración;
- una estructura sintáctica que sea menos pasiva o que directamente pide algo del servidor (en lugar de simplemente informarlo que se quiere algo); y
- una explicación de variaciones regionales (si existen).

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es demasiado amplia y las respuestas van a ser completamente subjetivas y regionalizadas. Sugeriría acotarla un poco. La primera respuesta sería simplemente decir "Mi hija quisiera una torta, por favor" pero las variaciones de esto son muchas. Además las maneras de pedir **comida** son iguales a las maneras de pedir casi cualquier otra cosa.

Answer (score 1):

En restaurán, puedes decir

> Voy a tomar el huachinango.
>
> ¿Me trae una orden de espaguetti, por favor?
>
> El filete de pescado viene con arroz?  [...] Si, eso, por favor.  Gracias.
>
> Una comida corrida, por favor.
>
> Una orden de papa frita, por favor.
>
> El pollo a la parrilla se ve bien. [El mesero ahora pregunta algo, por ejemplo, "Sí, señora, viene con arroz o papa frita."] Con arroz, por favor, gracias.

En familia, se puede decir

> ¿Me sirves un plato de sopa, por favor?
>
> ¿Puedo tomar un poco de pastel, o hay que dejarlo para la fiesta?
>
> Pásame otra piececita, por favor.  Te salió riquísimo, gracias.
>
> Creo que me cabe una pieza más.  (Extendiendo el plato.)  Gracias, Tía.

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que hablar más formalmente no significa hablar educadamente y esto es algo que he sostenido en otras respuestas: [¿Qué connotación tiene la construcción impersonal al pedir permiso o cosas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/qu%C3%A9-connotaci%C3%B3n-tiene-la-construcci%C3%B3n-impersonal-al-pedir-permiso-o-cosas/25834#25834)

Si quieres ser amable, tienes que aprender a pedir y no solo aprender a decir lo que quieres.

Con:

> Mi hija quisiera una torta.

podemos darnos cuenta de que estás siendo cortés, pero no educado.

Y ¿cómo podemos lograr esto?

¡Preguntando, pidiendo y sobre todo añadiendo: **buenos dias, por favor y gracias**!

---

edit:

Adicionalmente, una técnica es saber si estás llevando a cabo una comunicación asertiva; esto se logra a través de preguntarte si con lo que estas diciendo puedes esperar la respuesta que necesitas.

Entonces, si dices:

> Mi hija quisiera una torta.

¿Puedes esperar una respuesta?

Comment: algun dia se cumplira y podre usar autocorrector y spellcheck en español en la oficina, lo se !

Comment: +1 por resaltar la parte del por favor y gracias. Se dice por ahí que los hispanoablantes pecamos de utilizarlas poco, lo cual es llamativo para los extranjeros. Así que: gracias :)

Comment: spellcheck activado... no fue tan difícil

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algo similar a:

> ¿Puedes traerle una torta mi hija por favor?

Comment: El condicional añade aún más cortesía: "¿Podrías traerle una torta?". Todavía es más cortes utilizar el usted: "¿Podría traerle una torta?".